# python-for-in statement not terminating itself

Tags: python

I am learning python while using `for` statement loop is not terminating itself to do so I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

[image]

as u can see nothing is happening after ......

[image]

after using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> the statement got terminated

i m window user currently working on python 2.7.10
i have already read many post for this problem but find non solution please guide me

Answer (score 5):

The interpreter waits for the rest of the for loop, so just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the loop will execute.

Answer (score 2):

When working in the python interpreter, a line starting with three dots signals that it is waiting for a block to continue (blocks are created by for, if, while, def, class, and other similar statements).

Even if you put everything on one line (which python only allows if the block is exactly one line) as you have done, the interpreter still waits for you to finish the block.

Anytime that enter a statement and see that, you should first make sure that you have finished what you intended to enter (as you have) and then enter just a blank line (just hit enter) on the next line to signal to the interpreter that the block is done.